# Atualização de conteúdo

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de atualizar o conteúdo de uma página sem ter que ficar consultando o conteúdo periodicamente. Seria algo parecido com um chat ou como os "likes" do facebook onde ao fazer uma postagem e outras pessoas interagissem com esta postagem eu conseguiria ver esta interação mesmo sem ter que atualizar a página. Espero que tenha ficado claro.

Comment: Olá, Bem-vindo ao SOpt. Sua pergunta é um bocado ampla, o que não seria problema num Fórum, mas num site de perguntas e respostas é um pouco mais complicado. Sua pergunta gera respostas baseadas em opiniões, permitindo várias respostas corretas e diferentes.

Comment: Sim, tem várias formas de criar o que você deseja.

Comment: Bom dia , é um pouco complexa a resposta , pois pode ser feito de varias formas. Eu particularmente uso Ajax para fazer consultas sem dar um Refresh na pagina.

Comment: Tá vendo, existe o Ajax. Sempre tem o Ajax.